# JSONException String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, json, string, cucumber-java, jsonexception

I am trying to convert string to JSONObject. This is my code:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str);
```

Vehicle.feature file contains :

```
    Scenario: Create a vehicle with valid json request
    Given vehicle json for VehicleService
    """
        "{\"vin\" : \"VIN5\", \"brand\" : \"Toyota\", \"model\" : \"Innova\", \"year\" : \"2017\", \"color\" : \"Red\", \"modelCode\" : \"1234\", \"type\" : \"M\", \"countryCode\" : \"JP\", \"isConnected\" : \"true\", \"isActive\" : \"true\"}"
    """
    When performing POST on VehicleService url /add
    Then VehicleService should return status code 200
```

VehicleStepDefs contains:

```
@Given("^vehicle json for VehicleService$")
public void submitValidVehicleRequest(String vehicleJson) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(vehicleJson);
    request = given().and()
            .header("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .accept(ContentType.JSON)
            .body(obj);
    request.then().log().all();
}
```

My error looks like this :

```
org.json.JSONException: Value {"vin" : "VIN5", "brand" : "Toyota", "model" : "Innova", "year" : "2017", "color" : "Red", "modelCode" : "1234", "type" : "M", "countryCode" : "JP", "isConnected" : "true", "isActive" : "true"} of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
        at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:159)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
        at com.examples.demo.VehicleStepDefs.submitValidVehicleRequest(VehicleStepDefs.java:43)
        at ?.Given vehicle json for VehicleService(Vehicle.feature:8)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Check your imports.

Here is the running code:

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class TestJson {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("{\"vin\" : \"VIN5\", \"brand\" : \"Toyota\", \"model\" : \"Innova\", \"year\" : \"2017\", \"color\" : \"Red\", \"modelCode\" : \"1234\", \"type\" : \"M\", \"countryCode\" : \"JP\", \"isConnected\" : \"true\", \"isActive\" : \"true\"}");
            System.out.println(obj.get("model"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Output: Innova

Answer (score 0):

I am using the latest org.json jar json-20190722.jar

And i am able to print the json string without any issues, you can refer my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "{\"vin\" : \"VIN5\", \"brand\" : \"Toyota\", \"model\" : \"Innova\", \"year\" : \"2017\", \"color\" : \"Red\", \"modelCode\" : \"1234\", \"type\" : \"M\", \"countryCode\" : \"JP\", \"isConnected\" : \"true\", \"isActive\" : \"true\"}";

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str);
        System.out.println(obj.getString("brand"));
        // this also works when we are not sure of the return type of the resultant object
        System.out.println(obj.get("brand"));

    }
```

When i try changing the

> System.out.println(obj.getString("brand"));

to

> System.out.println(obj.getJSONArray("brand"));

I got this exception

> Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["brand"]
>   is not a JSONArray.   at
>   org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:752)     at
>   com.christmas.Main.main(Main.java:14)

which is clearly mentioning that the result is not of **JsonArray** type.

It is better you post your logic and complete stacktrace .

Comment: I am writing cucumber tests. I have to pass json into the request body. I have updated the question with more details

Answer (score 0):

It seems the response string was encoded with another type (such as `UTF-8` with *BOM*). Try adding following code snippet then convert it again.

```
vehicleJson = vehicleJson.substring(vehicleJson.indexOf("{"), vehicleJson.lastIndexOf("}") + 1);
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(vehicleJson);
...
```

Comment: Now I'm getting the exception : org.json.JSONException: Expected literal value at character 1 of {\"vin\" ...